# NodeJS, React on Heroku, Socket.io gives error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

**Help pls!** I am making a website with Node/Express and React on Heroku. 
Server.js serves an expresshandlebar template on client side, rendering App.js

So far everything was working, until I tried to implement Socket.IO. Socket.IO works perfectly on localhost but gives an error on Heroku:

**VM63:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://mysite:8080/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

Here is the relevant portion of the code:

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('Connection started');});
```

**App.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var new_socket = io.connect();
```

---

I have read many sites, and tried many alternatives, such as:
1) setting on both client and server socket.io 'path' and 'transports'

```
path: '/socket.io-client'
transports: ['websocket']
```

2) Trying WebSockets as recommended by Heroku. This throws another error 'error 503'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.io = socket.connect(yourpath, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false,
});
```

First, you need to connect to exactly socket server. Could you try above code, I'm using that for my project

Comment: Woah u r a genius! This did the trick! No more errors, my console is logging the messages sent by the server and client. Now, could you explain how this works?

Comment: By default, a long-polling connection is established first, then upgraded to "better" transports (like WebSocket). So our config will force them to skip use long-polling