# nodejs + express + socket.io > socket client connection issue on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

Im trying to make a little chat, using NodeJS, Express ans socket.io

For debugging Im using localhost, log4js, and locally it is working fine, socket.io is working with no problem.

But when I try to deploy it on remote server, it isnt working.
Here is a link https://cryptic-fjord-64553.herokuapp.com/
Ofc, I googled, wrote similar topics, tried a lot of stuff, but it isnt working.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>
> engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":404}

or

> engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":0}

My server, app.js includes this:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
logger = require('log4js').getLogger();
server = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(server),
```

this commented block instead server=.. and io=.. above when Im trying to deploy my app on the remote server (heroku)

```
/* 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
var https = require('https'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    server = https.createServer(app),
    io = socketio.listen(server, {log:false, origins:'*:*'});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000)); 
*/
```

When I try to deploy app on heroku, I comment server.listen.. block below

```
var pug = require('pug'),
port = 4000;

server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1', ()=>{
    var addr = server.address();
    logger.level = 'debug';
    logger.debug('listening on ' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/socket.io.js', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');
});

app.get('/socket.io/socket.io.js', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');
});


app.get('/jquery.js', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
});
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const amazingStuff = 'Its amazing stuff, ',
date = new Date;

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('pages/index', {
    title: 'main page',
    message: date,
    showChat: false
});

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{

socket.on('newUserJoin', (userName)=>{


    socket.session = {};
    socket.session.userName = userName;
    socket.session.address = socket.handshake.address;
    socket.session.id = socket.id;

    socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', socket.session);
    socket.emit('user', socket.session)
    socket.emit('userLisr', io.length)

    logger.info('user ' + socket.session.userName + ' / ip ' + socket.session.address)
    logger.info('user count: ' + io.engine.clientsCount)
    logger.debug(socket.session)

    var clients = io.sockets.connected,
        clientList = {};
    
    for (var i in clients){
        if(clients[i].session) clientList[i] = clients[i].session;
    }
    
    socket.emit('clientList', clientList);

})

//get a new message and share it to all users
socket.on('newMessage', (message)=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('shareMessage', message)
})

})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

versions:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.15.3",
     "jquery": "^3.2.1",
     "log4js": "^2.3.3",
     "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
     "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
   }
```

client, main.js:

```
var socket = io();
//var socket = io.connect('https://cryptic-fjord-64553.herokuapp.com/');
```

and handlers

and here is adding scripts in html(pug), first works locally, commented stuff are attempts I tried to do for deploying on heroku, but it doesnt work.

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
//-script(src='/socket.io.js')
//-script(src='https://cryptic-fjord-64553.herokuapp.com/socket.io.js')
```

U cant open the link above and take a look whats going on in the console. There are no warnings regarding client side script, I mean main.js file, so it can connect to the server and main.js knows what is 'io'. So it seems like its ok with links in the html and socket.io connection to the server. So probably its problem in the server side app.js

How can I force it to work on heroku?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961408/nodejs-react-on-heroku-socket-io-gives-error

Comment: I tried. Still no works. May be I do somthing wrong, but.. I cant understand how can var io = require('socket.io-client'); works in the client side, cuz I got error "require is not define"